# Join to Dataframes based on partial string matches in python

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, nltk

I have two dataframes with a common key-product names, what i want to do is create a third dataframe by joining the previous two based on partial string matches with 80-90% similarity, the datasets are quite large, i had tried using `tfidf` from `scikit-learn`, but i keep losing my reference index. In below example:Mini  Wireless Bluetooth Sports Stereo Headset and OnePlus 6 Sandstone Protective Case both need to come in df3, Help will be much appreciated. Output[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDd4p.png)

Example-

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.DataFrame({'Product_Name1': ['Mini  Wireless Bluetooth Sports Stereo Headset', 'VR Box 3D Smart Glass With Remote Controller', 'OnePlus 6 Sandstone Protective Case'],'Price1': [40000, 50000, 42000]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'Product_Name2': ['Mini  Wireless Sports Stereo Headset', 'VR Box 3D Smart Glass With Remote Controller', 'OnePlus 6 1Sandstone Protective Case'], 'Price2': [40000, 50000, 42000]})
df1set=df1.set_index('Product_Name1')
df2set=df2.set_index('Product_Name2')
df3=df1set.join(df2set,how='inner')
df3
df1
df2
```

[First dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCGh4.jpg)

[Second dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oT2AS.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: Please add your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is fuzzy matching. Fuzzy matching is used to compare strings which are very similar to each other. You can use `fuzzy wuzzy` for this.

Example of fuzzy matching

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process
process.extractOne('Mini Wireless Bluetooth Sports Stereo Headset', df2.Product_Name2)

('Mini  Wireless Sports Stereo Headset', 95, 0)
```

This value has a 95% match.

I have changed the order of df2 for demonstration.

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'Product_Name1': ['Mini  Wireless Bluetooth Sports Stereo Headset', 
                                    'VR Box 3D Smart Glass With Remote Controller',
                                    'OnePlus 6 Sandstone Protective Case'],
                  'Price1': [40000, 50000, 42000]})

df1

    Product_Name1                                   Price1
0   Mini Wireless Bluetooth Sports Stereo Headset   40000
1   VR Box 3D Smart Glass With Remote Controller    50000
2   OnePlus 6 Sandstone Protective Case             42000


df2=pd.DataFrame({'Product_Name2': ['Mini  Wireless Sports Stereo Headset',
                                    'OnePlus 6 1Sandstone Protective Case',
                                    'VR Box 3D Smart Glass With Remote Controller'],
                  'Price2': [40000, 42000, 50000]})

df2

     Product_Name2                                  Price2
0   Mini Wireless Sports Stereo Headset             40000
1   OnePlus 6 1Sandstone Protective Case            42000
2   VR Box 3D Smart Glass With Remote Controller    50000
```

Now we write a function which matches each value of `df1 Product_Name1` with every value of `df2 Product_Name2` and return the index of df2 where it matched the highest.

```
def fuzzy(x):
    closest_match = process.extractOne(x, df2.Product_Name2.values)[0]
    index = pd.Index(df2.Product_Name2).get_loc(closest_match)
    return index
```

The we use [apply](http://das.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to get the result

```
df1['match'] = df1['Product_Name1'].apply(fuzzy)
df1

Product_Name1                                      Price1   match
0   Mini Wireless Bluetooth Sports Stereo Headset   40000   0
1   VR Box 3D Smart Glass With Remote Controller    50000   2
2   OnePlus 6 Sandstone Protective Case            42000    1
```

As I don't have your expected output, I'm gonna merge them.

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='match', right_on=df2.index)

   Product_Name1                                  Price1    match   Product_Name2   Price 2 

0   Mini Wireless Bluetooth Sports Stereo Headset   40000   0        Mini Wireless Sports Stereo Headset            40000
1   VR Box 3D Smart Glass With Remote Controller    50000   2        VR Box 3D Smart Glass With Remote Controller    50000
2   OnePlus 6 Sandstone Protective Case             42000   1        OnePlus 6 1Sandstone Protective Case        42000
```

Let me know if it works for you

Comment: Thanks for the code, however the results don't match . For example the match suggests- Huawei Nova 2i - Smartphone - 5.50 - 4GB RAM - 64GB ROM - 16MP Camera - Black as a match to Apple iPhone 7 Plus - 128 GB,where as there was a different product for Huawei in that range