# Join big dataframes based on partial string-match between columns

Tags: python, pandas, string, merge, partial-matches

Two DataFrames have **gene** and **isoform** names that are not formatted the same way. I'd like to do a join and add the df2 columns `name, isoform` for all partial string matches between the `isoform (df2)`  and the `name (df1)` in both DataFrames. `df2` is a key for the **isoforms/genes**, where a gene can have many isoforms. In `df1`, basically an output from a gene-quantification software (SALMON) the `name` field has both, the **gene and isoform** in it. I cant use regex since **isoforms** have variable suffixs, such as ".","_", "-", and many others.
Another important piece of information is that each `df1["Name"]` cell has a unique **isoform**.

**Piece of dfs to merge:**

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': {0: 'AT1G01010;AT1G01010.1;Isoseq::Chr1:3616-5846', 1: 'AT1G01010;AT1G01010_2;Isoseq::Chr1:3630-5894', 2: 'AT1G01010;AT1G01010.3;Isoseq::Chr1:3635-5849', 3: 'AT1G01020;AT1G01020.11;Isoseq::Chr1:6803-8713', 4: 'AT1G01020;AT1G01020.13;Isoseq::Chr1:6811-8713'}, 'Length': {0: 2230, 1: 2264, 2: 2214, 3: 1910, 4: 1902}, 'EffectiveLength': {0: 1980.0, 1: 2014.0, 2: 1964.0, 3: 1660.0, 4: 1652.0}, 'TPM': {0: 2.997776, 1: 1.58178, 2: 0.0, 3: 4.317311, 4: 0.0}, 'NumReads': {0: 154.876, 1: 83.124, 2: 0.0, 3: 187.0, 4: 0.0}})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'gene': {0: 'AT1G01010', 14: 'AT1G01010', 30: 'AT1G01010', 46: 'AT1G01020', 62: 'AT1G01020', 80: 'AT1G01020', 100: 'AT1G01020', 116: 'AT1G01020', 138: 'AT1G01020', 156: 'AT1G01020'}, 'isoform': {0: 'AT1G01010.1', 14: 'AT1G01010_2', 30: 'AT1G01010.3', 46: 'AT1G01020.1', 62: 'AT1G01020.10', 80: 'AT1G01020.11', 100: 'AT1G01020.12', 116: 'AT1G01020.13', 138: 'AT1G01020.14', 156: 'AT1G01020.15'}})
display(df1)
display(df2)
```

**Desired output:**

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'gene': {0: 'AT1G01010', 1:"AT1G01010", 2:"AT1G01010", 3:"AT1G01020", 4:"AT1G01020"},'isoform': {0: 'AT1G01010.1',1:"AT1G01010_2", 2:"AT1G01010.3", 3:"AT1G01020.11", 4:"AT1G01020.13"}, 'Length': {0: 2230, 1: 2264, 2: 2214, 3: 1910, 4: 1902}, 'EffectiveLength': {0: 1980.0, 1: 2014.0, 2: 1964.0, 3: 1660.0, 4: 1652.0}, 'TPM': {0: 2.997776, 1: 1.58178, 2: 0.0, 3: 4.317311, 4: 0.0}, 'NumReads': {0: 154.876, 1: 83.124, 2: 0.0, 3: 187.0, 4: 0.0}})
#"Name" column from df1 is not necessary anymore. (the idea is to replace it for gene and isoform)
display(df3)
```

**Real dfs size:**

df1 = 143646 rows × 5 columns

df2 = 169499 rows × 2 columns

*(since `df1` may not have all the isoforms detected, it's always smaller than `df2`)*

**I tried some answers i found online, but since this dfs have a huge size, many need 50gb of RAM or so...**

*Already checked:* [Merge Dataframes Based on Partial Substrings Match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64372367/merge-dataframes-based-on-partial-substrings-match), [Join to Dataframes based on partial string matches in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53846559/join-to-dataframes-based-on-partial-string-matches-in-python), [Join dataframes based on partial string-match between columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52265419/join-dataframes-based-on-partial-string-match-between-columns)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is it expected that `AT1G01020.1` matches `AT1G01020.11`? and `AT1G01020.10` matches `AT1G01020.13`?

Comment: No, sorry (edited): **AT1G01020.11** and **AT1G01020.1** are different isoforms. I added more rows to df2 to clarify this example. Thanks!

Comment: so, to be clear you want a full match on gene and isoform?

Comment: Yes. Partial is requested since df1 has a large field that may not always be separated by ";". Isoform suffixes may also contain leters such as "_ID2".

Comment: How else can it be separated? You need to come a with a logic at some point ;)

Comment: For sure it's a special character (such as ";", ",", "-"), sometimes (the easy ones), the output just gives you the isoform. This depends on the Annotation used, this may vary from species to species, my idea behind this is to be as general as possible. *Special character* as separators is a good way to go i guess. (I've been struggling many days with this...). Thanks!